# Newtonsoft.JSON package added, but getting namespace errors when trying to use it

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I recently decided to create a new project and import my previous assets (without plugins, etc.) in order to have a clean project. Among other things I had problems with the "old" package Newtonsoft.Json, based on google searches probably because it was included into unity some month ago.

So, in my new project I added the following package, which should be the official unity package if I am not mistaken:
[image]

In Visual Studio I had the expected error before adding the using line.

[image]

I followed the suggestion and added:

```
using Unity.Plastic.Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and the error disappeared within Visual Studio as expected. So far, so good, I assumed...

However, back in Unity I now get the following error log:

```
 The type or namespace name 'Plastic' does not exist in the namespace 'Unity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Even after some research I do not understand what exactly the problem is or where something is missing and I hope you can help me.

Comment: d you also reference according assembly in your assembly definition (in case you are using those) ?

Comment: `probably because it was included into unity some month ago.` .. it has been a package available via the package manager already for some years now ;) The "official" but alpha package came in 2018 the first pre-release in [2019](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0/changelog/CHANGELOG.html) and was even included by default when creating new projects for a while ... which Unity version are you using?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the first sentence at this page, which mentioned the Feb 22.  https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Install-official-via-UPM. Anyway, I do not understand that I get the suggestion to add the mentioned "using Unity.Plastic.Newtonsoft.Json;" line, which afterwards causes errors. Where exactly is the problem here?

Comment: it should usually only be `using Unity.Newtonsoft;` .. not sure where the other suggestion comes from but I suspect `Plastic SCM` might be installed for the project? And yes 2022 it was finally converted into an "officially maintained" package .. but has been around since 2019 as a pre-release ;)

Comment: I probably found the reason in another thread and I still cant believe it... A restart of my computer probably solved the problem. Don't know if a restart of Unity and Visual Studio would have been enough. But now the suggested using is correct --> "using Newtonsoft.JSON" and the problem is gone. Finally. Quite annoying constellation...